# Using replace() method in python by index

Tags: python, replace

I want to do something like this.

```
example_string = "test"
print(example_string.replace(example_string[0], "b"))
```

expecting the output

```
best
```

however because the letter "t" is being passed into the method the t at the end also gets replaced with a "b". Resulting in the output

```
besb
```

How do I do it in a way that would result in the output "best" instead of "besb"?

Comment: You may want to try something like `new_str = "b" + example_string[1:]` . `replace(a,b)` is used for swapping all occurrences of string `a` with `b`.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to substitute the first 't' character of a string with 'b' ?

Or is the index the key to decide what to replace (instead of the t)

Comment: @Lynch: That's for replacing the *first* occurrence of a substring, not a *specific* occurrence of a substring.

Comment: I cant answer because its closed, but now I understand. This should works: `word = "test"; i = word.index('t', 2); word[0:i] + "b" + word[i+1:]`. Of course if you know the id of the char you want to replace instead of a letter you can directly set the variable `i`. If you need to substitue strings you could adapt it using the `i+len(substring)+1` to determine where the string ends.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that `.replace(old, new)` returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of `old` have been replaced with `new`.

Instead, you can swap the character at index `i` using:

```
new_str = old_str[:i] + "b" + old_str[i+1:]
```

Answer (score 5):

Check [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

You can use

```
example_string.replace(example_string[0], "b", 1)
```

though it would be much more natural to use a slice to replace just the first character, as @nbryans indicated in a comment.

Comment: That works for this case, but then what if you want to replace `example_string[3]`?

Comment: Note that your question was specifically how to replace the first occurrence of a character. (see [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))  This is a different question.  Don't use `replace()` where it is not appropriate, then.  As noted, use slices when you want to act upon a particular location of a string (or other sequence such as a list or tuple).  So for your new question: `s = example_string[:3] + "b" + example_string[4:]`

Answer (score 1):

```
example_string.replace("t", "b", 1)
```

Comment: That works for this case, but then what if you want to replace `example_string[3]`?